# How can I get the last 12 months sales subtotals in a table?

Tags: php

I have this code so far which gives me the subtotals for each product for a given month.

```
 <?php
    include("dbaseconn.php"); 




    $query = "SELECT product, SUM(qty) FROM sh_orders GROUP BY product"; 

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    // Print out result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<table width='1050'>"  ;
      echo "<td width='400'>";
        echo "". $row['product']. " ";
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo "". $row['SUM(qty)']. "" ;
      echo "</td>";
        echo "<br />";
    }
    ?>
```

TABLE STRUCTURE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sh_orders` (
  `building` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `qty` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unik` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `co_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unik` (`unik`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

I want to show the last 12 months sales - SUM (qty) does that for me, but I need to see each month separately with each product and its total sales for that month. I need this in one table showing each month with each product and total for that month

```
EXPECTED RESULT
Month:    January 2012    Feb 2012   Marc 2012
Product1: 124                105         76
Product2:  34                 23         56
Product3:  12                  5          6
```

I am new to this so please show patience if I ask a million questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product,sum(qty),DATE_FORMAT(product_month, '%Y-%m') as month 
FROM sh_orders 
WHERE product_month BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
AND now() group by  DATE_FORMAT(product_month, '%Y%m'),product
```

Each product have some quantity in same month and different days. First group by month, same product quantity summed each month. Second group by product, avoid product duplication in same month

Comment: Each product have some quantity in same month and different days.
first group by month, same product quantity summed each month.
second group by product, avoid product duplication in same month

Comment: Let me add the explanation to the answer itself.

Comment: The code I am trying is as follows: I get the total sales for units using SUM, the qty field is the number of units sold, I then use GROUP so that when the SUM is calculated for one product, it then prints the product name and quantity and then moves on to the next product and repeats the process until all products have been calculated. Hope this is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

change your query to

```
  $query = "SELECT product, SUM(qty) FROM sh_orders where Product_month between '2011-01-01' and '2012-01-01' GROUP BY product";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query that you need:

```
SELECT order_date, product, SUM(qty) as sum_qty
FROM sh_orders 
WHERE order_date > DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date), product
```

[`sqlfiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d6c0b/2)

---

The result is an array in this format:

```
array(
    array(
        'order_date' => '2012-09-02',
        'product'    => 'p2',
        'sum_qty'    => '2'
    ),
    array(
        // etc...
    )
);
```

You just have to loop through it and display the result as a table. If you have problems with creating the table it would be better to accept an answer here and ask a new question because it's more related to `html`, `loops` and `arrays`.

Comment: Ok the response has been amazing so far thanks everyone. I think maybe I am not explaining clearly what I want to do. I want to get a report that gives each product unit sales for each month. So for example Jan2012 Product1 23, Product 3 12 then Feb 2012 Product1 35, Product3 42 and so on and so on. I tried to post a picture of what I am trying to achieve but it wont accept a picture upload/. I might also need help in formatting the look of the result.

Comment: Yes thank you, I tried it and the query now works. I need to put it into a report format as I have shown in my original question, any ideas on how I can get that right?